# Could an "undo vote" option be added, for close votes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, vote-to-close

This is probably good to be considered for any types of votes, but I'm especially asking about the close vote because of the special significance they have over the usual up/down voting.

This was brought to mind by a particular post:  [Is it practical to run a weekly lunch-hour game of D&D with my coworkers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5123/197)

The original wording of the thread was something along the lines of "Is it a good idea to...".  I voted to close because the question's wording made it too susceptible to being subjective/argumentative.  I also made a point to (as I've suggested in another thread) comment on the post, to address the reason for my close vote.

However, the OP has since changed the title and content of his question to be a bit more agreeable.  Though it seems the question will not likely get voted closed, I'd like to have an option to un-do my own close votes for this and similar cases which might otherwise end up closed.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After Mr. Atwood's leaving SE, the issue was revisited and apparently approved.  You can see that according to the comments at the very end of [this answer's thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949), as well as implied by [the status-declined tag being replaced with status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).  Note that, like votes on comments, if you VTC and then rescind that vote you will be unable to VTC again on that question in the future, even if it is edited, undergoes a rollback, or is otherwise changed.

Answer (score 6):

This has already been asked and declined.

- **[Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)**

  - [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949)

Note that your close vote will age away harmlessly after a day or two.

Comment: For information: once you've clicked on that link, you scroll to the bottom of the page for Jeff's answer.

Comment: @Graham That's habit for me on `[status-declined]` answers.  I'll link that as well.

Comment: This answer is out of date now.